# Verifying and safely serving youtube links in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, security, youtube

I would like to allow users to post embed youtube links and have it display in my nodejs app.

Node provides a handy way of parsing urls:

```
var url = require('url');
var youtube = url.parse("https://www.youtube.com/embed/eisKxhjBnZ0");

console.log(youtube);

/*
{ protocol: 'https:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'www.youtube.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'www.youtube.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/embed/eisKxhjBnZ0',
  path: '/embed/eisKxhjBnZ0',
  href: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/eisKxhjBnZ0' }
*/
```

I am planning on checking the `host` to make sure the source link is indeed from official Youtube, and then saving the `pathname` to the db. When a user requests a page, I would load the video by piecing together hardcoded url info + the pathname:

ie,

```
// Verify Youtube source link
if (youtube.host == 'www.youtube.com') {
    saveToDB(youtube.pathname);
} 

// ... Later ...
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com" + video.pathname></iframe>
```

Would this be a secure way of serving embedded videos from youtube? Also would only checking `host`, but serving the entire `href` be safe too rather than appending to a hardcoded url?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, one should check the entire href, not just the top level host, before serving it up. As you can see in the code, the url is being parsed and the path extracted. There are no checks on the actual content - so no claim can be made about its security.

But in this case, the real assurance is YouTube itself. One can safely assume that YouTube is better equipped than most to detect and remove malicious content uploaded to its servers. So the last step is somewhat redundant - checking the host by comparing it to a hardcoded value doesn't ensure anything - in that it will always return true (it might complain because of the *www.* in the front but that's a non-issue). One could just as well use the original url instead of appending the extracted pathname to a hardcoded hostname.